# Regression coefficients between vector-valued variables

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, vector-autoregression

Sorry for the basic question, but I'm a bit confused on the notation.

Let say we have a random vector of $m$ predictors variables ${\bf X} = (X_1,\ldots,X_m)^{\intercal}$ that are used to predict $n$ variables indicated with ${\bf Y} = (Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)^{\intercal}$

The general linear regression model can be written as
\begin{equation}
    Y_i = \sum_{j=1}^m A_{ij}X_j + \epsilon_i \qquad i = 1,\ldots,n~,
\end{equation}

or in vector form
\begin{equation}
{\bf Y} = A{\bf X} + {\bf \epsilon}.
\end{equation}

I call $\Sigma({\bf Y},{\bf X})$ the cross-covariance matrix $n\times m$ of elements $\text{cov}(Y_i,X_j)$ and $\Sigma({\bf X})$ the covariance matrix of ${\bf X}$.

Given this premises and notation, I found written that the $n\times m$ matrix of regression coefficients is simply

\begin{equation}
    A = \Sigma({\bf Y},{\bf X}) \Sigma({\bf X})^{-1}~,
\end{equation}

but I don't understand where this formula came from.
I read that should be possible to derive this formula easily via Yule-Walker procedure, but I don't understand how.
Why don't we use the standard approach of ordinary least square methods, where we found the regression coefficients by minimizing the residuals?

Comment: Isn't this just $n$ separate ordinary least squares regression of the rows of $Y$ against the same design matrix $X$?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I was confusing the design matrix ${\bf x}$ with the random vector ${\bf X}$, but they are basically the same thing when you write them in components, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @whuber that made me notice that this problem must be equivalent to $n$ separate ordinary least square regressions, where the coefficients of the $k$-th regression are given by the $k$-th row of $A(k,:)$.

If this is the case, I should be able to compare the standard OLS estimator with $A = \Sigma({\bf Y},{\bf X}) \Sigma({\bf X})^{-1}$ and obtain the same result.

So the standard OLS estimator is
$$A(k,:) = \hat{\beta}_k = {\bf x}^\intercal y_k({\bf x} {\bf x}^\intercal)^{-1}$$

where I denoted with ${\bf x}$ the $m\times N$ design matrix, where each column is one of the $N$ realizations of the random vector ${\bf X}$. Now I realize that the two things are equivalent, since writing in components $\Sigma({\bf X})_{ij} = \sum_{t=1}^N x_{i,t}x_{j,t} = ({\bf x}{\bf x}^\intercal )_{ij}$ and the same happen for $\Sigma({\bf Y},{\bf X})$.